# Map hex character

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

If I want the output `g`, I can create a map like this:

```
imap <F2> <C-V>U10400g
```

However for output `f`, it causes a problem:

```
imap <F2> <C-V>U10400f
```

as the `f` is confused as part of the character. I can work around by adding
leading zeros:

```
imap <F2> <C-V>U00010400f
```

but I would prefer a terminating key if possible. I came up with this:

```
imap <F2> <C-V>U10400<CR>f
```

but it puts a newline between the two characters. Is it possible to do what I am
trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation explicitly recommends using the maximum number of digits. See [`:help i_CTRL-V_digit`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V_digit):

> Normally you would type the maximum number of characters.  Thus to enter a
>   space (value 32) you would type `<C-V>032`.  You can omit the leading zero, in which case the character typed after the number must be a non-digit.  This
>   happens for the other modes as well: As soon as you type a character that is
>   invalid for the mode, the value before it will be used and the "invalid"
>   character is dealt with in the normal way.

I have found, however, that a command such as [`CTRL-]`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-%5D), which triggers abbreviation, without inserting a character, is enough to break the sequence, without an undesirable side effect.

This seems to work fine:

```
inoremap <F2> <C-V>U10400<C-]>f
```

But I'd still recommend the solution using the three leading zeroes, as it's less "hacky" and it's the one recommended in the documentation.